# logback: can one emit a thread's priority?

Tags: logback

In our application we are currently "playing" with thread priorities to avoid that background activities delay the frontend. For this it would be very helpful to see the thread priorities in the log file. We are using logback.

Is there a possibility to emit a thread's priority as part of the logback pattern? Our pattern currently looks like this:

```
        <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5level %logger - [S:%X{sessionId}] [U:%X{userName}] [T:%thread] - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
```

Is there something like `%prio` or so? I found nothing corresponding in any logback docs that I found so far. Or can one somehow define own `%xyz`-tags in logback that e.g. trigger some method?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the bandwidth used. Meanwhile I found https://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html (chapter "Creating a custom conversion specifier") which describes how to write your own tags / "layout conversions".